# Django: "Product matching query does not exist."?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm new to programming following along a Udemy Python/Django e-commerce tutorial while creating the cart_update function. I ran into this error below. I used ForeignKey for user in my models. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong; and how should I be thinking about this kinda of error going forward?

thanks in advance SO communinty

```
DoesNotExist at /cart/update/
Product matching query does not exist.

/Users/duce/Sites/RENUecommerce/src/carts/views.py, line 20, in cart_update
    product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id) …
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from inventory.models import Product
from .models import Cart


def cart_update(request):
    product_id = 1
    product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    #product_obj = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
    return redirect('cart:update')
```

models.py

```
import random, os
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.backends.base import features
from django.db.models.fields import SlugField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.urls import reverse
from .utls import unique_slug_generator

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def featured(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(featured=True)

        
    def get_by_id(self, id):
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=id) # Product.objects == self.get.queryset()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first()
        return None

    def search(self, query):
        lookups = Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query) |Q(price__icontains=query) |Q(tag__title__icontains=query)
        return self.get_queryset().filter(lookups).distinct()


class Product(models.Model):
    title       =models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug        =models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description =models.TextField()
    price       =models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, default=0.00)
    image       =models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    featured    =models.BooleanField(default=False)

    obj = ProductManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return "/inventory/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from .views import(
     cart_home, 
     cart_update,
)

app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', cart_home, name='home'),
    path('update/', cart_update, name='update'),
]
,,,
```

Comment: There is no product with `product_id=1`.

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong models.py file

Comment: but the model is irrelevant here: you use ` product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)` and `product_id=1` on the previous line, so you fetch a `Product` with primary key equal to one, but no such `Product` record exists.

Comment: Thanks!! Took me a while to figure things out read a lot of documentation. Look for that coffee in the next coming days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get the message: "Product matching query does not exist."

Is because of the code: "product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)"

There is no row in the model Product with a ID = 1. You first need to make 2 Product items before you can retrieve a product with ID 1, by the way its not the best way to retrieve a object right by its ID unless you know what product has ID 1.